# Nodejs Alert only run once

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have the following function set up to run upon a form submit.

```
const Putaway = () => {
  //create state for use later
  const [wave, setWave] = useState("");

  //submit a form to send data
  const onSubmitForm = async (e) => {
    try {
      const body = { wave };
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/yourstage", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
      });
      alert(`${pack_hu} has been successfully moved to ${stage_location}`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  };

  //return the form html
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1 className="text-center mt-3">Putaway</h1>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmitForm}>
        <div className="form-group row">
          <label htmlFor="Wave" className="col-sm-2 col-form-label">
            Wave:
          </label>
          <div className="col-sm-10">
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="Wave Number"
              pattern="\d{10}"
              title="10 digits required"
              maxLength="10"
              value={wave}
              onChange={(e) => setWave(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="text-center">
          <button type="submit" className="btn-lg btn-primary">
            Save
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

However, my ALERT line only run once (the first time i reload the page), although i submitted my form multiple times.

I want the alert to run each time i click my submit button. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must prevent default behaviour on first line of the method onSubmitForm

```
e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried it and it works! can you explain to me why is this so?

Comment: onClick has a default behaviour due to which page gets reloaded, so technically your method gets invoked but by the time it can do anything page gets reloaded, and the same page renders back.
check this for more understanding:- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Got it. Thank you.